# AngularJS + Jasmine + JWT Token in $http requests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, jwt, ngresource

I'm trying to build some test with an API that works with JWT authentication tokens, but the factories that I'm trying to test use `$resouce`, which needs to be configured with `JWT Token`. In the app I configure it in the `.config`, but in `Jasmine` I have no idea how it should be, because Jasmine runs **before** the app.

I'm trying to find the way to configure Jasmine's requests or maybe run the tests **after** the app is configured.

Here I'm trying to configure the `Jasmine`'s requests.

```
describe("Sync.Remote", function () {
    var Remote = angular.injector(['sync.remote']).get('Remote')('Test', 'test')
      , testingObject = { name: "Mario", lastname: "López" }

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpProvider_, _jwtInterceptorProvider_, _$resourceProvider_) {
        $httpProvider = _$httpProvider_
        jwtInterceptorProvider = _jwtInterceptorProvider_
        $resourceProvider = _$resourceProvider_

        jwtInterceptorProvider.authPrefix = "JWT "
        jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = function(config) {
            if(config.url.indexOf("http://some.website.com") === 0) {
                return "XXXXXXX-JWT-TOKEN"
            }
        }

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor')
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true
        $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false
    }))

    it("#_create es capaz de crear un objeto en la nube", function (done) {
        Remote._create(testingObject)
        .then(function (item) {
            expect(item.id).not.toBe(undefined)
        }, function (err) {
            expect(0).toEqual(1)
        })
        .finally(done)
    })
})
```

But it doesn't work because the `$resouce` service is inside the Remote factory, it is a dependecy actually. Any ideas?

Comment: could you include the code for your Remote factory and any error message it's producing?

Comment: A bit late commenting here but it sounds pretty obvious that you had to mock the resource provider.